# Redirect hundreds of subdomains to the main domain with path forwarding, use .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache

I want to redirect from a subdomain to domain along with URL path forwarding.

Example:

```
abc.example.com/products.html
```

TO

```
another.example/products.html
```

The trailing URL should be preserved.

We have more than 1000 subdomains created and some of them needs to be redirected to Domains. The subdomains are created virtually.

I am using Linux webserver and PHP as language.

I believe this can be done by changing IP of `another.example` to `example.com` and adding some codes in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Do you have access to the server config? Are you always redirecting to `another.example` - or could the target domain vary? Do your subdomains point to a common root directory at `example.com`?

Comment: The target domains vary. The subdomains are wildcard virtual subdomains. Do I have to create a Cpanel account for each of the target domains as well?

Comment: "Do I have to create a Cpanel account for each of the target domains as well?" - You don't have to create a "cPanel account", but the target domain must obviously resolve and the redirected resource must be available at the target domain.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe this can be done by changing IP of `another.example` to `example.com` and adding some codes in the `.htaccess` file.

You certainly should not be "changing the IP" of any domain. (What was your reasoning behind this?)

This sounds like a relatively simply redirect that can be performed in the `.htaccess` file. A *condition* is required that checks for the specific subdomain.

I assume all your "virtual" subdomains of `example.com` point to the document root of `example.com`. In which case you would put something like the following (using mod_rewrite) near the top of the `.htaccess` file in the root of `example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://another.example%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` (condition) checks for the specific subdomain/hostname (note that this is a *regex*). The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the requested URL-path, which is appended onto the end of the target domain.

Note that this is a temporary (302) redirect. Only change this to a permanent (301) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have tested this is working OK. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.